# Correct way of declaring resource path in html that works in both vs code and github pages?

Tags: html, visual-studio, github-pages

I just deployed a simple site with github pages and found that the resource path that works in vs code is not working on github pages:

1. This works in vs code, but not in github. This has a leading / at the start of the path for href

   `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/clone/clone.css">`
2. This works in github, but not in vs code. This is not having the leading /

   `< link rel="stylesheet" href="clone/clone.css">"`

I went through the absolute and relative paths and, if I use absolute path, it works in git pages but not in vs code:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/web-dev/clone/clone.css">
```

Can you please help me the correct way to reference resources that works in vs code and git pages.
I had published a repo couple of months back and did not face this error. Today, even that site has this issue.